# django 1.11 no changes detected

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello i am stuck to a point in django migrations i have created a model class in "connection" app's model.py but my ubantu 14.04 terminal still saying while running "python manage.py makemigrations" no changes detected, also i have specify the app name in above command but did't worked. Please help me out. Thanks
Here are my migrations:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
analytics
 (no migrations)
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
connection
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
reports
 (no migrations)
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

is there anything else is required please ask in comment.

And here is the table which i wanna add in db via model.py file of connection app.

```
class BModel(models.Model):
    user              = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reports_user")
    dataset           = models.ForeignKey(DatasetRecord, related_name="dataset_record")
    name              = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.id

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'
```

and here is the model.py file code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from daas.models import *
# Create your models here.
#on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,

class Dbconnection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="db_user")
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    port = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=3306)
    dbname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dbuser = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dbpassword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    connection_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    connection_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.id

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'


class DatasetRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="dataset_user")
    dataset = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sqlquery = models.TextField()
    connection = models.ForeignKey(Dbconnection, related_name="db_connection")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.id

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'


class Reports(models.Model):
    user              = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reports_user")
    dataset           = models.ForeignKey(DatasetRecord, related_name="dataset_record")
    row_dimension     = models.TextField()
    col_metrics       = models.TextField()
    report_type       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    report_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    custom_data       = models.TextField()
    query_json      = models.TextField()
    created_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.id

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'



class CustomDashboard(models.Model):
    user              = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="daas_userdashboard")
    dashboard_name    = models.TextField()
    created_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.id

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'




class CustomDashboardReport(models.Model):
    customdashboard   = models.ForeignKey(CustomDashboard, related_name="daas_customdashboardreport")
    report         = models.ForeignKey(Reports, related_name="Reports_daas_customdashboardreport")
    report_title      = models.TextField()
    custom_data      = models.TextField()
    created_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'

class Dashboard_Drill_Report(models.Model):
    user                  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="daas_dashboarddrillreport")
    customdashboard       = models.ForeignKey(CustomDashboard, related_name="daas_dashboarddrillreport")
    parent_report         = models.ForeignKey(Reports, related_name="parentreports_daas_dashboarddrillreport")
    child_report          = models.ForeignKey(Reports, related_name="childreports_daas_dashboarddrillreport")
    canvas_id             = models.TextField()
    created_date          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'daas'



class SalesMetadata(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    aggregation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:

        managed = False
        db_table = 'sales_metadata'


class SalesMetadataDemo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    aggregation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:

        managed = False
        db_table = 'sales_metadata_demo'

class FactOrderDemo(models.Model):
    business_date = models.IntegerField(db_column='Business_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    product = models.CharField(db_column='Product', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    brand = models.CharField(db_column='Brand', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    category = models.CharField(db_column='Category', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    channel = models.CharField(db_column='Channel', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    payment_method = models.CharField(db_column='Payment_Method', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.CharField(db_column='City', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    state = models.CharField(db_column='State', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sales = models.DecimalField(db_column='Sales', max_digits=34, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    discount = models.DecimalField(db_column='Discount', max_digits=34, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cancellations = models.DecimalField(db_column='Cancellations', max_digits=34, decimal_places=4)  # Field name made lowercase.
    total_orders = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='Total_Orders')  # Field name made lowercase.
    returns = models.CharField(db_column='Returns', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fact_order_demo'
        #unique_together = (('business_date', 'product', 'category', 'promotion', 'channel', 'payment_method', 'city', 'state', 'country'),)
```

Please help me i am using python verison 3.4.3 with django version 1.11

Comment: and is there anything else required to solve the problem please do comment.

Comment: make sure you have added `connection` app in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: yes its already added

Comment: can you add your settings.py  file to question

Comment: what info you wanna see in settings.py i can comment here and i have checked INSTALLED_APPS is okay because i have previously run the migration on this app, but this time not working dont know why

Comment: take in care that changes in non managed models (`managed = False`) won't trigger any migration.

Comment: @alfonso.kim but the table i am gonna add(BModel) do not contain managed = False.

Comment: What's up with those `app_label = 'daas'`? As far as I can see from the migration output, your app label should be `connection`.

Comment: @AKX are you sure that app_label should be same as the model file name? cant it be a different ?

Comment: @AKX i have tried your way... and that worked!!
Thanks but just wanna ask here... that several time i have use a different name or a same name in all app's model.py and they worked, why not this time, can u please clarify.

Comment: @CodeSnake Most of the time you shouldn't need an explicit `app_label = ` annotation if your models are correctly in each app's `models.py` (note: not `model.py`).

Comment: @AKX ok thanks this worked me, but i am still in confusion that i everything was working file with app_label = 'daas' and created others table as well, but why this time it is not working.

Comment: @CodeSnake It's hard to tell without seeing the full structure of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the app_label to the name of the app that you added in your installed_apps inside settings.py

app_label = 'connection'

Reference : [app_label django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/)

And the answer to "but i am still in confusion that i everything was working file with app_label = 'daas' and created others table as well, but why this time it is not working" is maybe this "If a model is defined outside of an application in INSTALLED_APPS, it must declare which app it belongs to" not sure until i see actual apps.